# Number of columns impact in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have around 200 columns in each row in a Cassandra table.
I have single node cluster as of now.

When I run about 100,000 records using CPP datastax driver, I am getting around 3,500 writes per second and 30,000 reads per second. However, when I keep all my columns in a single column in blob type excluding the primary key (partition key) in Cassandra, my performance multiplies hugely with 40,000 writes per second and 70,000 reads per second.

Does the number of columns make a performance impact in Cassandra?
Also, the data size of 1 row is hardly 1kB.

Answer (score 1):

Theres overhead in deserializing and serializing the data and keeping track of the different columns. In pre-3.0 the impact is much much worse as well, storing a ton of redundant data. Its a lot better in 3.0 but if your ok with doing the deserialization from blobs yourself and having limited debugging and statistic ability in db, you will get better performance.

Comment: Thanks Chris. So according to you the latency increases from cassandra nodes as the number of columns increase. Also, I would like to correct I had perforemed tests on 100,000 rows not 10,000.

Comment: It depends on the type of the columns on how long it takes to deserialize. It should be very minor though. Without seeing your code, theres a chance that if you parallelize your queries you can get closer throughput, but if your doing anything non-async or sequentially, adding latency to requests no matter how small will reduce your throughput (littles law). I highly recommend you test out your data models with cassandra-stress first, to rule out any inefficient use of client. 3k writes per second is horribly slow, it should be faster than reads.